# How to make IE11 behave like IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-11

My application works fine with IE8 but not in IE11. We are not in condition to make change in code as application code is huge.So i am using following code in the common top level jsp:-

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
```

but still application view is not same as when we manually run the page in compatible mode.What i have notice is that when i manually run the page in compatible mode document mode is set to 5(Default) but when i am using meta tag document mode is still set to Edge.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can Forcefully Emulate IE11 to behave similar to IE8.Add the below lines of code to your web.config file

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear/>
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```